# returnUrl always null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Well, just as the title says, the returnUrl parameter from my login action is always null, I followed default Internet Application example but I can't make it work (Im relatively new to MVC)

The view

```
@using MundialDeFutbol.Models
@using System.Web.Optimization
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h3 class="text-info">Login</h3>
<div class="separadorHorizontal"></div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Usuarios", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post,
    new { @class = "form-horizontal", @style = "margin-top: 20px;" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div id="loginErrors" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 ">
            <strong>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, null, new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "margin-top: 10px;" })
            </strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Nick" class="col-sm-2 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nick)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nick, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Nombre de usuario" })
            <strong>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nick, null, new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "display: block; margin-top: 10px;" })
            </strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Contraseña" class="col-sm-2 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contraseña)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Contraseña, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Escribe contraseña", @type = "password" })
            <strong>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contraseña, null, new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "display: block; margin-top: 10px;" })
            </strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Entrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

The controller

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous] // --> Preguntar
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] // --> Preguntar
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel usuario, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (IsValid(usuario.Nick,usuario.Contraseña))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usuario.Nick, false);
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => ModelState[key].Errors);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

And finally, I want to ask what does the "[AllowAnonymous]" and "[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]" decorators.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom authentification, you need to add in the method OnAuthorization : ReturnUrl = **filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl**

Example:

```
 public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
 {

    //Some logic here...
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                           new RouteValueDictionary(
                           new { controller = "Account",
                                             action = "Login", 
                                             ReturnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }));            
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are setting two things but using as one: in you .cshtml page you set below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Usuarios", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post,
new { @class = "form-horizontal", @style = "margin-top: 20px;" }))
```

but in you post Login action you give its name "returnUrl" like below:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel usuario, string returnUrl)
```

please check and try again, parameter is case-sensitive.

Comment: as you mentioned above: [AllowAnonymous] is an Attribute that can be used to decorate a Action or Controller, if so an anonymous user could access you web page;if not, login required to take further action; and another one [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] is used for defending against cross-site request forgery;

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. But no, it didn't change anything at all, GET "version" of Login doesn't even take the parameter "returnUrl", it's always null. It should save the url where the login link was clicked. This is weird as I did exactly the same thing as in the default example :|

Comment: does that address your issue? i mean unify the parameter name in the web page and in the action signation "RetrunUrl" and "returnUrl"? just like Ehsan Sajjad mentioned above.

Comment: Now all parameters have the same name (ReturnUrl), even the form, and still returns `null`

Comment: ensure that you give a value to the parameter returnUrl when you post your Login. check it in the url before you do post form. if everything is ok, i am real sorry i can not help you further. bad day. :o(

Answer (score 0):

In parameter you have :

```
new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }
      ^
      |
      |
```

but in action parameter is:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel usuario, string returnUrl)
                                                     ^
                                                     |
                                                     |
```